# Prevent search engine crawlers access for multiple-hostnames used as CDN

Tags: seo, iis-7.5, robots.txt, hostname, google-search-console

I have configured multiple hostnames on our shared hosting account hosting MVC4 website. I did it for loading static resources from these multiple hostname to gain some speed by making parallel requests. All these hostnames are mapped to the same site / application in IIS. And then we changed URLs of static resources to load them from these hostnames. Basically, its like loading from a CDN (we're not really using CDN, but just making it load it parallel.)

However, I want to block search engines and other crawlers to access these multiple-hostnames / subdomains. Otherwise it will list them in search listings.

I think to add robots.txt, but these domains are using same application. So I it's already have robots.txt which is there for my main domain.

Any idea on how to prevent crawlers from crawling these additional hostnames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below rule to your web.config under  node.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^robots\.txt$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^cdn\.yourdomain\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/cdn.robots.txt" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Google Webmaster Tools you can set preferences for "canonicalization". This is the terminology used to describe duplicate content with a preferred source (more precisely it refers to the preferred source itself). Google have a discussion of their policies on [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359) and [canonicalization](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) in the answers section of Webmaster Tools.

To summarise the page the simplest/best approach is to set a "preferred domain" in your Webmaster Tools site settings and set up link elements in your duplicate pages with `rel="canonical"` to indicate your preferred source for SEO purposes.

> If you want http://www.example.com/dresses/greendress.html to be the
> canonical URL for your listing, you can indicate this to search
> engines by adding a  element with the attribute rel="canonical"
> to the  section of the non-canonical pages. To do this, create a
> link as follows:
>
> `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/dresses/greendress.html">`

Canonical links are not specific to Google. They are defined in [RFC 6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) and are known to also be supported by Yahoo and Bing since 2009.

> In regard to the link relation type, "canonical" can be described
> informally as the author's preferred version of a resource.  More
> formally, the canonical link relation specifies the preferred IRI
> from a set of resources that return the context IRI's content in
> duplicated form.  Once specified, applications such as search engines
> can focus processing on the canonical, and references to the context
> (referring) IRI can be updated to reference the target (canonical)
> IRI.

Setting up canonical links does not *prevent* search engines from crawling your duplicate pages but it should ensure your page rank and search links are correctly assigned (which is really the important part). In theory GoogleBot and other crawlers should eventually figure out which base url is the real content and shouldn't crawl your duplicate content as often or as intensely as your "primary" pages.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer with explanation. I have already looked at this. But this doesn't prevent crawling of such duplicate / cdn domain, so it is crawled, indexed and presented. Moreover, it increases resources consumption which are not required.. like it takes bandwidth, cpu, etc. resources to process those requests. Moreover, regarding declaring rel=cannonical, we're having a single application, and all cdn domains are just cname, so it requires additional changes into the application level which is certainly not desirable. The re-write suggestion for robots.txt works very well.

Comment: When you say the content is "indexed and presented" I'm curious which search engine(s) you are referring to. The whole point of `rel="canonical"` is to prevent exactly that and all the major search engines claim to support it. You might also not be aware that the link can be safely included in your primary pages (pointing back to itself) so there's no reason for your application to do anything but include the header as a static address.

Comment: If robots.txt works for you that's great but its likely you're harming your SEO in the process if other sites link to your CDN pages instead of your primary domain and you block crawlers from those CDN copies. If I remember correctly Google specifically advises NOT to do robots.txt blocking in the manner you're doing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for explanation.. I was not aware of Google advises not to block cdn url using robots.txt.. can you please share some authenticated links where google advises this. Moreover, cdn hostnames are there for cdn purposes and not any other. If other sites are using them, then there is something wrong in marketing being done. I will wait for your response on this.

Comment: Google Webmaster Help: Duplicates Page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en Near the middle: "Google does not recommend blocking crawler access to duplicate content on your website, whether with a robots.txt file or other methods. ... A better solution is to allow search engines to crawl these URLs, but mark them as duplicates by using the rel="canonical" link element, the URL parameter handling tool, or 301 redirects. In cases where duplicate content leads to us crawling too much of your website, you can also adjust the crawl rate setting in Webmaster Tools."

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, it is recommended to upload static contents in one subdomain and point all your CDN resources to your subdomain. Then block your subdomain using robots.txt file or using Google Webmaster tools.

Comment: Thanks.. But that would mean moving lot of resources to some other folder. Its difficult to maintain especially when we're talking of dynamic sites. Any other suggestions / idea.